# Left multiplication is homeomorphism w.r.t. the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

When studying connected components in matrix groups, we consider a closed subgroup $S$ of $GL_n(k)$ ($k$ algebraically closed field), where 'closed' refers to the fact that we can consider $GL_n(k)$ as an affine variety over $k$ endowed with the Zariski topology (in which affine varieties are exactly the closed sets).

Take $g\in S$ fixed. I want to show that left multiplication $\phi:S\to S: y\mapsto gy$ defines a homeomorphism. This map is clearly bijective. As for continuity, we would have to take a closed subset $V$ in $S$ (which is an affine subvariety) and show that $\phi^{-1}(V):=\{s\in S: gs\in V\}$ is closed (i.e., an affine variety) as well.

Let $V=V(I)$ for some radical $I\trianglelefteq k[S]$, then $\phi^{-1}(V) = \{s\in S: f(gs)=0, \forall f\in I\}$. How do I get this in the form $V(J)$ for some ideal $J$?

Comment: If you want to see the ideal explicitly then I think what you're after is the ideal consisting of regular functions $g^{-1}\cdot f$ for $f\in I$, where $(g^{-1}\cdot f)(s)=f(gs)$.

Comment: Could we use $J=\langle f\circ \phi:f\in I\rangle$?

Comment: That's the same thing, yes. If you have any morphism of varieties then the inverse image of $V(I)$ is $V(J)$ for your ideal $J$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think is a cleaner approach.

First, left multiplication by $g$ is a morphism $S\to S$: matrix multiplication is given by polynomials, so it's a morphism $M_n(k)\times M_n(k)\to M_n(k)$. Now restrict to the closed subvariety $\{g\}\times S$, and use the fact that $S$ is a subgroup to conclude that the restriction lands in $S$.

Next, note that left multiplication by $g$ is invertible: just left-multiply by $g^{-1}$. As this is also a morphism (by the same reasoning in the above paragraph), we see that $g\cdot -$ and $g^{-1}\cdot -$ are mutually inverse morphisms $S\to S$ (aka they are both isomorphisms). As a morphism is continuous with respect to the Zariski topology, $g\cdot -$ is a homeomorphism.